# What is the best way to get an accurate clickthrough rate with the Facebook Insights graph API (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, analytics, facebook-insights

I'm currently building a dashboard for a webapp that displays metrics for Facebook posts published from a specific Facebook page.
I'm using the graph API with "read_insights" and it's working well for the most part.
The only thing i'm stumped on is how to get an accurate clickthrough rate for a page's posts.
Previously I was using the following formula to get clickthrough rate:

```
clickthroughRate = (engagement / impressions) * 100;
```

However, this will give an inaccurate number as Facebook defines post engagement as "The number of people who clicked anywhere in your posts". My understanding is that this includes ALL click activity in the post... likes, comments, shares, even people who clicked on a profile pic in the comments feed. Obviously, this is not what I want. I really just want the number of people who clicked the link in the post.

I've poured through the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights) and I can't find anything that suggests that this is possible. However, if I download a csv from the Facebook insights page the metric is available and even has it's own column.

Is there no possible way to do this with the graph API?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To get app clicks you can use post_consumptions_by_type or post_consumptions_by_type_unique and in that breakout you can see link clicks.

The engagement rate that facebook uses can be taken from the graph api. It is `post_engaged_users*100/post_impressions_unique`